# Correct formulas for two wheeled robot motion

Tags: kinematics, rotation, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I'm trying to write a simulation of a two wheeled robot, which can be controlled by varying the speeds of his wheels, independently. However, the physics engine that I'm using can only rotate a body by a given angle, and/or apply a force to it. I'm trying to convert the given information (the speeds of the motors) into the force that should be applied to the robot.

The current formulas that I'm using have a caveat: when the two wheel speeds are identical, the speed with which the robot goes in a straight line is much greater than if I vary one of the speeds by a very small amount, and the robot's trajectory becomes a curve of very large radius. Here are the formulas (b is the distance between wheels):

```
R = (v1==v2 ? 0 :(b/2) *(v1+v2)/(v2-v1));
v = (v1 + v2) /2;
F = body.mass *(R==0 ? v : v *v /R);

Body.applyForce(body, { x: 0, y: 0 }, {
    x: Math.cos(body.angle) *F,
    y: Math.sin(body.angle) *F
});
```

I took these formulas from [this Robotics SE question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-is-a-suitable-model-for-two-wheeled-robots) and from the Wikipedia article on centripetal force. Also worth mentioning is that in this environment, the physics engine applies friction to the body. I'm not sure where I went wrong, could you please help me?

Comment: The formulas for $R$ and $v$ are right. But the $F$ seems to be wrong. Why are you taking $mv$ for force? (i.e when $R=0$)

Comment: Actually I'm not really sure what the Force should be in that case, all I know is that it should depend on v somehow (if v is low, F should be low, if v is high, F should be high)

Comment: $F$ can be calculated using $mv/t$ where $t$ is the time it takes for the car to accelerate to speed $v$, or you can use $mv^2/2d$ where $d$ is distance it travels to attain the speed $v$